# How to get Post Value in express JS

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to deploy a firebase function using express JS, but unable to get the post value, please help:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json(req.body) // giving buffer as given below
})

exports.tripDispatch = functions.region('asia-south1').https.onRequest(app)
```

response in postman I am getting is:

```
{
    "type": "Buffer",
    "data": [
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        48,
        57,
        53,
        51,
        52,
        57,
        52,
        52,
        54,
        55,
        50,
        48,
        49,
        48,
        53,
        49,
        49,
        57,
        52,
        49,
        52,
        53,
        54,
        50,
        13,
        10,
        67,
        111,
        110,
        116,
        101,
        110,
        116,
        45,
        68,
        105,
        115,
        112,
        111,
        115,
        105,
        116,
        105,
        111,
        110,
        58,
        32,
        102,
        111,
        114,
        109,
        45,
        100,
        97,
        116,
        97,
        59,
        32,
        110,
        97,
        109,
        101,
        61,
        34,
        116,
        114,
        105,
        112,
        73,
        100,
        34,
        13,
        10,
        13,
        10,
        49,
        48,
        48,
        13,
        10,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        45,
        48,
        57,
        53,
        51,
        52,
        57,
        52,
        52,
        54,
        55,
        50,
        48,
        49,
        48,
        53,
        49,
        49,
        57,
        52,
        49,
        52,
        53,
        54,
        50,
        45,
        45,
        13,
        10
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(req.body)`
 in your request handler ?

Comment: @yousoumar same thing I am getting at console.log

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your parsing process. Try to use the built-in parser of express, like so:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json(req.body) // giving buffer as given below
})

exports.tripDispatch = functions.region('asia-south1').https.onRequest(app)
```